# How can i control a frame movement with oculus quest's trackpad

Tags: aframe

Instead of walking around through the  Aframe scene, I want to look around using the controllers without body movements. Is it possible?

Comment: How bout something like [this](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/tree/master/aframe/controls)